# pom.xml goals runs in Eclipse but not in Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

I recently took over a Front end testing project. The thing wont run the goal when i run it in NB. but it runs it without problems in Eclipse... 
I can still manually select the file **/WorkflowStories.java and click on run tests. Then it runs.. but when i click on project and build or run tests... etc... it just wont run the goal....

Does anyone have any pointers for me where to start the search why the goal does not run... or am i missing where the goal should be executed?

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>at.dig</groupId>
    <artifactId>eprocure.test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>eprocure.test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <includepath>**/WorkflowStories.java</includepath> 
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbehave.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-web-selenium</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-junit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.21</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency> <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId> <artifactId>jbehave-guice</artifactId> 
        <version>3.9.5</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jbehave-guice-archetype</artifactId> <version>3.9.5</version> 
        </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.carlosbecker</groupId> <artifactId>guice-junit-test-runner</artifactId> 
        <version>1.1</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picocontainer</groupId>
            <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-pico</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
                <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>run-stories-as-embeddables</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <scope>test</scope>
                            <storyTimeoutInSecs>2000</storyTimeoutInSecs>
                            <includes>
                                <include>${includepath}</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.16</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When i click on run selenium test in any configuration i get this error:

```
Forking command line: cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\dev\eprocure\tests\eprocure.test\target\surefire\surefirebooter2755771664797425151.jar C:\dev\eprocure\tests\eprocure.test\target\surefire\surefire585909871144772322tmp C:\dev\eprocure\tests\eprocure.test\target\surefire\surefire3369166164771177265tmp"

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.476s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue May 02 11:12:30 CEST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/158M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-cli) on project eprocure.test: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-cli) on project eprocure.test: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:60)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.writeSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:641)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:615)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that Eclipse and NB run goals with a different set of flags. Execution maven goals from the pure command line may help you.